# WPF: How to recalculate CanExecute in ICommand in one ViewModel after changes in another ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF app with two buttons: Search and Properties.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<WrapPanel>
    <Button Content="Search Data" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" />
    <Button Content="Properties" Command="{Binding PropertiesCommand}" />
</WrapPanel>
```

Both buttons use commands that initialized in MainWindowViewModel:

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            SearchCommand = new SearchDataCommand(this);
            PropertiesCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenPropertiesWindow);
        }
        
        private async Task OpenPropertiesWindow()
        {
            PropertiesWindow propertiesWindow = new PropertiesWindow();
            propertiesWindow.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            propertiesWindow.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

When you click on the Search button, SearchCommand is called. CanExecute method of SearchCommand checks that 2 properties are set:

SearchDataCommand:

```
    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Settings.Default.ApiKey))
        {
            // show message box that property is not set
            return false;
        } 
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Settings.Default.UserId))
        {
            // show message box that property is not set
            return false;
        }

        return !IsExecuting;
    }
```

When I click Properties button, I open properties window where I can set these properties (ApiKey and UserId).

```
    public class PropertiesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //...

        public PropertiesViewModel()
        {
            SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveData, null);
            
            ApiKey = Properties.Settings.Default.ApiKey;
            UserId = Properties.Settings.Default.UserId;
        }

        private async Task SaveData()
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.ApiKey = ApiKey;
            Properties.Settings.Default.UserId = UserId;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

            SaveCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); //Event is handled in PropertiesWindow to call Close() method
        }
    }
```

Passing one ViewModel to another ViewModel is not a good idea from MVVM point of view since it leads to unneccessary coupling between view models.

And here is the question: I need to recalculate CanExecute in SearchDataCommand (to activate the button) when ApiKey and UserId properties are set and saved in PropertiesViewModel? How to do it correctly without breaking MVVM principles?

**Updated** according to the @BionicCode recommendations.

MainWindow:

```
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PropertiesBtn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PropertiesWindow propertiesWindow = new PropertiesWindow
            {
                Owner = this
            };
            propertiesWindow.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

PropertiesWindow:

```
    public partial class PropertiesWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly PropertiesViewModel _propertiesViewModel;
        
        public PropertiesWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _propertiesViewModel = new PropertiesViewModel();
            DataContext = _propertiesViewModel;

            _propertiesViewModel.SettingsRepository.SaveCompleted += PropertiesViewModel_SaveCompleted;
        }

        private void PropertiesViewModel_SaveCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
```

SettingsRepository:

```
    public class SettingsRepository
    {
        public string ReadApiKey() => Properties.Settings.Default.ApiKey;
        public string ReadUserId() => Properties.Settings.Default.UserId;
        
        public void WriteApiKey(string apiKey)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.ApiKey = apiKey;
            PersistData();
        }

        public void WriteUserId(string userId)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.UserId = userId;
            PersistData();
        }

        private void PersistData()
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            OnSaveCompleted();
        }

        public event EventHandler SaveCompleted;
        private void OnSaveCompleted() => SaveCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

SearchCommand:

```
    public class SearchCommand : ICommand
    {
        private bool _isExecuting;

        public bool IsExecuting
        {
            get => _isExecuting;
            set
            {
                _isExecuting = value;
                OnCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }

        public SearchCommand(Action<object> executeSearchCommand, Func<object, bool> canExecuteSearchCommand)
        {
            ExecuteSearchCommand = executeSearchCommand;
            CanExecuteSearchCommand = canExecuteSearchCommand;
        }

        public void InvalidateCommand() => OnCanExecuteChanged();

        private Func<object, bool> CanExecuteSearchCommand { get; }
        private Action<object> ExecuteSearchCommand { get; }

        private event EventHandler CanExecuteChangedInternal;
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
                CanExecuteChangedInternal += value;
            }

            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
                CanExecuteChangedInternal -= value;
            }
        }
        
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => CanExecuteSearchCommand?.Invoke(parameter) ?? !IsExecuting;
        public void Execute(object parameter) => ExecuteSearchCommand(parameter);

        private void OnCanExecuteChanged() => CanExecuteChangedInternal?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

MainViewModel:

```
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public SearchCommand SearchCommand { get; }
        private SettingsRepository SettingsRepository { get; }
        
        private readonly ISearchService _searchService;

        #region INotifyProperties
        //properties
        #endregion

        public MainViewModel(ISearchService searchService)
        {
            _searchService = searchService;
            
            SettingsRepository = new SettingsRepository();
            SettingsRepository.SaveCompleted += OnSettingsChanged;
            
            SearchCommand = new SearchCommand(ExecuteSearchCommand, CanExecuteSearchDataCommand);
        }

        private bool CanExecuteSearchDataCommand(object parameter)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SettingsRepository.ReadApiKey()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "Set API Key in the application properties.",
                    "Configuration Error",
                    MessageBoxButton.OK,
                    MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return false;
            } 
            
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SettingsRepository.ReadUserId()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "Set User id in the application properties.",
                    "Configuration Error",
                    MessageBoxButton.OK,
                    MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return false;
            }

            return !SearchCommand.IsExecuting;
        }

        private async void ExecuteSearchCommand(object parameter)
        {
            SearchCommand.IsExecuting = true;
            await ExecuteSearchCommandAsync(parameter);
            SearchCommand.IsExecuting = false;
        }

        private async Task ExecuteSearchCommandAsync(object parameter)
        {
            //Search logic with setting INotifyProperties with results
        }
        
        private void OnSettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => SearchCommand.InvalidateCommand();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

PropertiesViewModel:

```
    public class PropertiesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public ICommand SaveCommand { get; }
        public SettingsRepository SettingsRepository { get; }
        
        #region INotifyProperties
        //properties
        #endregion

        public PropertiesViewModel()
        {
            SettingsRepository = new SettingsRepository();
            
            ApiKey = SettingsRepository.ReadApiKey();
            UserId = SettingsRepository.ReadUserId();
            
            SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveData, null);
        }

        private async Task SaveData()
        {
            SettingsRepository.WriteApiKey(ApiKey);
            SettingsRepository.WritemUserId(UserId);
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Still I'm not sure that current classes design doesn't violate MVVM principles. At the end I get some sort of result. But here are the things that confuse me:

- View models have separate `SettingsRepository` objects. Is it OK that `MainViewModel` subscribes to `SettingsRepository.SaveCompleted` to call `InvalidateCommand` and `PropertiesViewModel` subscribes to its own instance just for closing the `PropertiesWindow`? It looks like some sort of mess.
- For some reason, `CanExecuteSearchDataCommand` is called twice and it seems that `InvalidateCommand` does too much work for the price of loose coupling here. I mean it seems it reacts on the MessageBox closing. If I remove MessageBox and just return false, then it works as expected.
- Are there any resources to read about these mechanisms and how to properly use them (like `InvalidateCommand`) in details, except for MSDN?

Comment: Did you consider using [CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested) and let your commands listen to the [CommandManager.RequerySuggested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.commandmanager.requerysuggested) event (which your `RelayCommand` implementation might already do)?

Comment: You need to trigger the `CanExecuteChanged` event so the UI can refresh itself. A simple solution if you [expose](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.ComponentModelDemo/blob/0060e9a9b6cb06181be9831b9d1273aa36a13596/KGySoft.ComponentModelDemo/ViewWpf/Commands/SwitchableWpfCommandBase.cs#L30) a writable `bool CanExecute` property. By doing so a `RelayCommand`-like delegated implementation may look like [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.ComponentModelDemo/blob/master/KGySoft.ComponentModelDemo/ViewWpf/Commands/SimpleWpfCommand.cs).

Comment: @KlausGütter Actually I'm in a process of learning MVVM concepts more deeper. And currently my RelayCommand is pretty simple - it has only `Func<Task> _callback`. I'll take a look at this CommandManager, thank you.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg Yes. But the PropertiesViewModel isn't connected to MainViewModel that is passed to SearchCommand. I mean, I think I need to subscribe to RelayCommand's `CanExecuteChanged` in SearchCommand or something like this. I cannot sort it out in my head at the moment.

Comment: @Dragon: "_I need to subscribe to RelayCommand's CanExecuteChanged_" - no, from the view model you only need to set the `CanExecute` property of the command. The binding engine will do the subscription to be able to change the enabled state of the bound control.

Comment: "_Passing one ViewModel to another ViewModel is not a good idea_" - it _may_ be a bad idea if the view models are meant to be logically independent. But if they are logically in a parent-child relation, then it may totally make sense if a child view model has a `Parent` property or something like that.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg "_no, from the view model you only need to set the CanExecute property of the command_" - it seems I'm dumb since for me these are two different objects. When I execute Properties command, PropertiesViewModel is updated. When I execute Search command - MainViewModel is upadted. I think I need to learn mode theory on the MVVM.

"_if they are logically in a parent-child relation, then it may totally make sense_" - Properties window is a child of the MainWindow. Especially taking into account that application is pretty simple and there's only one way to open PropertiesWindow.

Comment: Looks like the answer below will lead you on the right track but just wanted to reply to what you said about not wanting the view models to be coupled to each other. In my experience this is fine and often necessary. The important thing is to keep the VM layer separated from the Views other than through bindings. There's really nothing wrong IMO with the VMs being aware of each other in which case they can update one another's command executability statuses in a much more straightforward way.

Comment: @JustAnswertheQuestion Yes. Messaging from Community Toolkit works great. Regarding my fears about tight coupling - I make an effort to keep the relations between classes as loosely coupled as possible, which is something I prioritize in my coding style.

Comment: How do you implement your commands? If you delegate the CanExecuteChanged event to the CommandManager.RequerySuggested event, WPF will invoke CanExecute automatically for you. Otherwise you must observe the view model class that your command owning class depends on. Then raise the CanExecuteChanged event explicitly.

Comment: Persisting data is not the job of the view model. This is the responsibility of the model. Also view model does not reference any controls like MainWindow or handles (show/close) dialogs. You usually show dialogs from code-behind of a view class. If you fix all this MVVM violations you automatically get the proper design that will solve your original issue.

Comment: Then always use the RelayCommand, which enables the defining view model class to gracefully interact with the command's CanExecute delegate. Since you are already using the RelayCommand there is no reason to implement a SearchCommand. It only complicates the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution is breaking the MVVM pattern and therefore creates the issue you are currently struggle to solve.

- The *View Model* is not allowed to handle/reference controls or participate in UI logic. This means, showing dialogs from the *View Model* is not allowed. Everything UI related (dialogs are UI) must be handled in the *View*.
- The *View Model* is not responsible to persist data. This is the responsibility of the *Model*.

The following solution solves your problem gracefully by fixing the MVVM violation and by improving the class design:

1. Because data persistence is the responsibility of the *Model* you usually would wrap the actual read/write operations into a class that the *View Model* classes can use, preferably as a shared instance. This allows any class (like `MainWindowViewModel` for example) to observe data changes of the data repository. This is now possible because read/write operations are no longer spread across the application. The *View Model* should not know any details about the underlying data store that the *Model* is using (whether data is persisted using the file system or a database for example).
2. Then let your command expose a `InvalidateComand()` method that explicitly raises the `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` event.
   Note that when delegating the `CanExecuteChanged` event to the `CommandManager.RequeryREquested` event, WPF will automatically invoke `ICommand.CanExecute` (for example on mouse move).

This way both your classes `MainWindowViewModel` and `PropertiesViewModel` are completely independent of each other. Both depend on the repository: on class to write to the user settings and the other to observe data changes.

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```cs
class MainWindowViewModel
{
  public MainWindowViewModel(UserSettingsRepository userSettingsRepository)
  {
    // Use the Model to read and write data
    this.UserSettingsRepository = userSettingsRepository;

    // Because the repository is used application wide we now have a single object to observe for setting changes.
    // When the repository reports changes, we explicitly invalidate the command
    this.UserSettingsRepository.SaveCompleted += OnUserSettingsChanged;

    this.SearchDataCommand = new SearchDataCommand(ExecuteSearchDataCommand, CanExecuteSearchDataCommand);
  }

  private void OnUserSettingsChnaged(object sender, EventArgs e) => this.SearchDataCommand.InvalidateCommand();

  private void ExecuteSearchDataCommand(object? obj) => throw new NotImplementedException();
  private bool CanExecuteSearchDataCommand(object? arg) => throw new NotImplementedException();

  public SearchDataCommand SearchDataCommand { get; }
  private UserSettingsRepository UserSettingsRepository { get; }
}
```

**SearchDataCommand.cs**

```cs
class SearchDataCommand : ICommand
{
  public SearchDataCommand(Action<object?> executeSearchDataCommand, Func<object?, bool> canExecuteSearchDataCommand)
  {
    this.ExecuteSearchDataCommand = executeSearchDataCommand;
    this.CanExecuteSearchDataCommand = canExecuteSearchDataCommand;
  }

  public void InvalidateCommand() => OnCanExecuteChanged();

  public bool CanExecute(object? parameter) => this.CanExecuteSearchDataCommand?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
  public void Execute(object? parameter) => this.ExecuteSearchDataCommand(parameter);

  private void OnCanExecuteChanged() => this.CanExecuteChangedInternal?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

  public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged
  {
    add
    {
      CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
      this.CanExecuteChangedInternal += value;
    }
    remove
    {
      CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
      this.CanExecuteChangedInternal -= value;
    }
  }

  private event EventHandler CanExecuteChangedInternal;
  private Action<object?> ExecuteSearchDataCommand { get; }
  private Func<object?, bool> CanExecuteSearchDataCommand { get; }
}
```

**UserSettingsRepository.cs**

```cs
// A class of the Model (MVVM)
class UserSettingsRepository
{
  public void WriteApiKey(string apiKey)
  {
    Properties.Settings.Default.ApiKey = apiKey;
    PersistUserData();
  }

  public void WriteUserId(string userId)
  {
    Properties.Settings.Default.UserId = userId;
    PersistUserData();
  }

  public string ReadApiKey(string apiKey) => Properties.Settings.Default.ApiKey = apiKey;

  public string ReadUserId(string userId) => Properties.Settings.Default.UserId = userId;

  private PersistUserData()
  {
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    OnSaveCompleted(); 
  }

  private void OnSaveCompleted => SaveCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); //Event is handled in PropertiesWindow to call Close() method    
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private void OnShowPropertiesDialogButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    // TODO::Show PropertiesWindow dialog
  }
}
```

**PropertiesViewModel.cs**

```cs
class PropertiesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public PropertiesViewModel(UserSettingsRepository userSettingsRepository)
  {
    // Use the Model to read and write data
    this.UserSettingsRepository = userSettingsRepository;   
  }

  private void ExecuteSaveDataCommand(object parameter)
  {
    this.UserSettingsRepository.WriteApiKey(this.ApiKey); 
    this.UserSettingsRepository.WriteUserId(this.UserId); 
  }

  public SaveCommand SaveCommand { get; }
  private UserSettingsRepository UserSettingsRepository { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As `SearchDataCommand` is depending on `MainWindowViewModel` and the viewmodel can be changed after it is passed to the command, there should be a way to inform the command about the fact that the viewmodel changed, so it can issue a `CanExecuteChanged` on its own.

I'd add a `Changed` event to the viewmodel, trigger that on every call to `PropertyChanged` and subscribe to it in the command.

**EDIT**:
If the `PropertiesViewModel` is just used in the `PropertiesWindow` and has no connection to anything (regarding the scope of this post), you should think of some messaging functionality.

Create a `PropertiesChangedMessage` and publish it from the `PropertiesViewModel`. Then subscribe to the message in the `SearchCommand` and trigger the `CanExecuteChanged` event.

For such messaging have a look at the [community toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger).

Comment: `MainWindowViewModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `PropertiesViewModel` also implements it. `SearchDataCommand` takes `MainWindowViewModel` as an argument and modifies corresponding data on execution. But `PropertiesCommand` is RelayCommand that opens separate Window (PropertiesWindow) with `PropertiesViewModel` in the behind. And thus properties in `PropertiesViewModel` are not connected to `MainWindowViewModel` and `SearchDataCommand` correspondingly. Currently I'm investigating CommandManager as Klaus Gütter suggested.

Comment: Then let `MainViewModel` additionally subscribe to `PropertiesViewModel` `PropertyChanged` or also add a `Changed` event there. If there are more sub-viewmodels, it may be necessary to rethink the viewmodel structure.

Comment: And that is the question. `PropertiesViewModel` is created in `PropertiesWindow` c-tor. If I instantiate `PropertiesViewModel` in `MainWindowViewModel` and pass it to `PropertiesCommand`, I will be able to subscribe to `PropertiesViewModel` property chagned event. But won't whit connection between two view models violate MVVM principles?